# Is there an easy way to manage multiple phpunit configurations?

Tags: php, configuration, continuous-integration, phpunit

I have some unit tests I want to run often, and others (like the selenium functional tests) that are slow and take more setup. Also, there is a need for the clover reporting when the ci server runs the tests, I don't always want them.

Are there ways to add switches to the xml config? Or is it best keep multiple different configs and tell it which every time?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Keeping multiple configs is a good and common approach.

```
phpunit.xml.dist
phpunit.xml.travis
phpunit.xml.jenkins
phpunit.xml.ci
```

That allows activating the logger clover in only one file, like only on CI "phpunit.xml.jenkins". But it's possible to append it on the CLI "--coverage-clover", when invoking phpunit.

Another option is to group the tests into "slow" and "fast".
You need the @group annotation for that.

```
// phpunit.xml.ci
<groups>
  <include>
    <group>fast</group>
  </include>
  <exclude>
    <group>slow</group>
  </exclude>
</groups>
```

That's also possible from the CLI, with options like "--group", "--exclude-group".

http://phpunit.de/manual/3.7/en/appendixes.annotations.html#appendixes.annotations.group

It's also possible to set PHP constants inside the phpunit configuration files to "flag" where you are and decide what to run inside the Tests.

```
// in phpunit.xml.*
<php>
   <const name="PHPUNIT_RUNS_ON_CI_SERVER" value="true"/>
</php>

// somewhere in a PHP test file
if (defined('PHPUNIT_RUNS_ON_CI_SERVER') === 1)
{ 
    // run CI stuff
}
```

Comment: So you have all of the phpunit files in your project, and then setup build tasks that pass them as an argument? Or are you suggesting that as part of the deployment you copy/link one to phpunit.xml, and the others are not used?

Comment: Yes, i would suggest to have all phpunit config files in your project. Like /project/tests/travis/phpunit.xml.travis for instance. and in .travis.yml you would just trigger that config file via CLI. Example: https://github.com/burnbright/silverstripe-shop/tree/master/tests/travis and https://github.com/burnbright/silverstripe-shop/blob/master/.travis.yml#L24

Comment: I'm considering using naming like phpunit-ci.xml, phpunit.xml,, phpunit-coverage.xml and phpunit-jenkins.xml, and then putting those in build.xml as different tasks, each running with an arg that chooses the correct phpunit.xml. The vanilla named one would run unit tests only, with no coverage reporting.

Comment: Please keep in mind that Jenkins expects certain loggers to be active for later report generation : http://jenkins-php.org/configuration.html